# How do you move VMs with managed disks between resource groups

Tags: azure

Created a VM recently and managed disks are now an option, so after looking at all the benefits I decided we should use these for VMs going forward. Now I want to tidy up the resource groups I'm managing. I can move all the old VMs between resource groups, but the new VM can't be moved. The validation fails saying that the resource group of the managed disk cannot be changed. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving VMs with managed disks isn't supported yet - it will be soon.

Comment: Brian, can you define soon?

Comment: It's not supported on the portal but it is possible with PowerShell and Azure CLI

Comment: @SohailAhmed can you provide the links for that please?

Comment: I posted as an answer since it contains several links.

Answer (score 5):

By now, we're moving VMs with managed disk following this procedure:

1. Stop VM
2. Create managed disks snapshots
3. Create new managed disks from snapshots in the new Resource Group
4. Deploy new vm using using managed disks in the new Resource Group

I'm sure moving managed disk is comming soon (I hope)

Comment: Do you have a script that you use to do this? Or are you doing it manually?

Comment: We're using Powershell script. Sadly, we had to move lots of VMs to a new RG because of a reorganization

Comment: @AntonioJ.AguilarBravo Can you provide the script you are using for this?

Answer (score 1):

Managed disks are supported for move as of September 24, 2018.

You'll have to register to enable this feature.

```
Register-AzureRmProviderFeature -FeatureName ManagedResourcesMove -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Compute
```

The registration request initially returns a state of Registering. You can check the current status with:

```
Get-AzureRmProviderFeature -FeatureName ManagedResourcesMove -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Compute
```

Wait several minutes for the status to change to Registered.

After the feature is registered, register the Microsoft.Compute resource provider. Perform this step even if the resource provider was previously registered.

```
Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Compute
```

Source:
[Move resources to new resource group or subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#virtual-machines-limitations)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move `Azure` Managed Disks at this time but the following steps can be used to snapshot and redeploy them between resource groups/subscriptions.

1. Copy snapshot of a managed disk in same subscription or different subscription with [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-copy-snapshot-to-same-or-different-subscription) or [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-linux-cli-sample-copy-snapshot-to-same-or-different-subscription)
2. Create a virtual machine from a snapshot with [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-create-vm-from-snapshot) or [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-linux-cli-sample-create-vm-from-snapshot)